# SQL Server stored procedure: set with into variable

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

How can I set result from with query into variable?

I have variable

```
declare @ResultVar float;
```

and with query

```
 WITH CTE AS
 (
        SELECT [Val]...
 ) 
 SELECT SUM([Val]) 
 FROM CTE
```

I don't want to use `SELECT`, this is part of a SQL Server stored procedure.

Comment: Just use `SELECT @ResultVar = SUM(Val) FROM CTE` - what's wrong with that??

Comment: this is sql procedure i don't wanna display this partial result, isn't any way to avoid this and just copy this result to variable?

Comment: What @marc_s has suggested will do exactly that, and not display any results.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Per @marc_s's comment:

```
 WITH CTE AS
 (
        SELECT [Val]...
 ) 
 SELECT @YourVar = SUM([Val]) 
 FROM CTE
```

A `select` that assigns a variable does not return a rowset to the caller of the stored procedure.  Try it.